# 741 vs MCP6004 for low power application

Tags: operational-amplifier

For experimental - educative purpose, I'm trying to control one 3-color led with the following circuit:

[image]

- Power: single rail, 5v.
- Signal generator: triangular 0-5v, 500 Hz (in next step, signal generator should be replaced by an op-amp circuit, could be a rectangular generator followed by integrator).
- operational amplifier: 741 in comparator configuration. v+ from signal generator; v- from variable resistor R1=100 K .
- red led with R2=160 ohms resistor (in the future, circuit will be triplicated for each color of the RGB led).

In this way, the triangular signal is converted to a WPM (width pulse modulated) where the width of the pulse is controlled via the variable resistor.

Problem: using a 741 op-amp the led intensity does a "jump" when reaching the low/high limits, probably due to its operational margin levels (741 seems not designed for 5v power supply).

Do you think [MCP6004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQMGH.png) can be used instead of 741 in this project to solve this issue ? (another possibility is [TL974](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl971.pdf))

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When will the 741 finally die?

Comment: Start with the LM358 (dual) or LM324 (quad). Cheapest and vvvv common op amps. See if they will do. Go from there (they too are olde olde parts)

Comment: Interesting options, nice they support +-15V. LM324 is not classified as rail-to-rail (in manual I read Voh=Vcc-1.5) ¿could be this fact an issue for this circuit?

Comment: *"741 seems not designed for 5v power supply"* Gee, d'ya think!?  -1 because you obviously haven't bothered to read the datasheet.  We are not here to read the datasheet to you.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Too much aggressive. Do you feel better if I write "741 is not designed for 5v power supply" ?

Comment: If you know the 741 isn't specified for 5 V supply, then why are you even asking about using it with a 5 V supply!?  Either you didn't read the datasheet, or this is a really dumb question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: sorry, I'm not here for this kind of conversations, but to learn and share about electronics and collaborate with the ones with same objective.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum supply rail on some 741s is recommended as +/-10 volts so this might immediately exclude it. I believe the ST uA741 can work down to a single +5V rail but there are much better choices of op-amp compared to this diminutive dinosaur.

My personal list of reasons **not to use** a 741 are listed below: -

- Minimum recommended power supply rails are +/- 10 volts
- Input voltage range is typically from -Vs + 2 volt to +Vs - 2 volt
- Input offset voltage is typically 1 mV (5 mV maximum)
- Input offset current is typically 20 nA (200 nA maximum)
- Input bias current is typically 80 nA (500 nA maximum)
- Input resistance is typically 2 Mohm (300 kohm minimum)
- Typical output voltage swing is -Vs + 1 volt to +Vs - 1 volt
- Guaranteed output voltage swing is -Vs + 3 volt to +Vs - 3 volt
- Supply current is typically 1.7 mA (2.8 mA maximum)
- Noise is 60 nV/sqrt(Hz) for LM348 (quad version of 741)
- GBWP is 1 MHz with a slew rate of 0.5 V/us

The LM741A is slightly better but still a dinosaur in most areas.

The MCP6004 is suitable for the 5 volt supply but I would encourage you, line by line, to make comparisons with the 741 as I have listed above.

Comment: Suggestions: make a self answered (community wiki??) q&a "Why not to use a 741" we can then use to link everywhere, maybe even into the 741 tag wiki, should such exist.

Comment: @PlasmaHH sounds a good idea.

Comment: @Andyaka: thanks for your answer, In addition to discard the 741, I need to select an alternative. I'm thinking in MCP6004. Do you think it will be valid for this application ? (forum rules doesn't allows me to ask for a replacement suggestion).

Comment: I'll firstly quote my answer "I would encourage you, line by line, to make comparisons with the 741 as I have listed above". Second, I'll point out that this is what EEs do. Third, I'm not about to make guesses on some description that doesn't include a schematic.

Comment: @PlasmaHH OK I've done what you suggested but how do I make it "community wiki". TBH I don't really understand what a community wiki Q&A is d'oh!

Comment: @Andyaka: schematic included.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I think you should make the triangle wave more like 4 volts p-p or at least guarantee it cannot hurt the inputs if it exceeds the rail. You also need to ensure the LED current can be driven from the op-amp. Other than that it should work. Supply decouplers are always needed BTW.

Comment: @Andyaka: according to my information, MCP6004 is rail-to-rail. It doesn't means that it supports full 0-5v input?

Comment: Yes it is R2R and the analogue input range is the full rail but your triangle waveform generator might be set wrong and exceed the over-voltage limits and do some harm to the inputs. It's a caution!